# mysql database normalisation/modeling

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to move my office into a database application. Here is what I got:
[image]
<sub>(source: [phunkei.de](http://www.phunkei.de/images/erd_office.png))</sub>

**companies** and **individuals** inherit (1:1 relation) from **clients**. That is because both of them can be a "client" and receive a bill and I would like to reference to a single table in **orders**.
There is another relationship between companies and clients: a many to many.
I hope you guys have some ideas for improvements, because I'm not really sure of this.

edit: companies and individuals will have some different fields ...

Comment: Why do companies and individuals have relation between them? Just trying to understand better. Many to many relationship usually gets resolved by adding a table that contains only two keys of two tables i.e it will contain companies_id and individuals_id in it.

Comment: Yes there will be another table between them. Well there can be many individuals in a company I have to deal with. Sometimes a person can also be related with more than one company, so that's why there is a relation. The thing I find "unpretty" is the inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider myself to be a database newbie, so take this suggestion with a grain of salt. I would personally be tempted to set this up as a star schema. Here is an example from:

[Microsoft Technology: BI Dimensional Model - Star Schema](http://blog-mstechnology.blogspot.com/2010/06/bi-dimensional-model-star-schema.html)

[image: star schema]

This should allow for quick query speeds (if everything is indexed correctly) and should allow you to easily add on more attributes to query. One trade-off for quick queries is updating the Fact table. This will be slower due to indexing.

This has worked well for me in past projects but, again, I am by no means a qualified database professional.

Comment: thanks for this example. But my problem is, that I have 2 different kinds of customers (companies and individuals).

Comment: Could you use companies/individuals as an attribute of customer id, instead of creating a separate table for each?

Comment: that was my first design. But to keep it flexible and valid to possible extensions, i decided for the inheritance. But I will mockup both now and do some tests. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good, let us know how it goes. Just one other note around flexibility and extensions. You can use Date_To, Date_From, and Current_Record fields on your Dimension Tables (these are all the tables joined to Sales_Facts in the table above). This will give you historical reporting capabilities (google: slowly changing dimensions for more info). And avoid snowflaking (google this too)! Okay, I'm done rambling, best of luck!